# Average score per student in a Sharepoint list

Tags: infopath, lookup-column, filter, calculated-column-formula, flow

I have a SharePoint list which is a feedback score dump from PowerApps. The PowerApps has a drop down to select which student **email**(out of many) they are scoring.

Every entry is a new row in the SharePoint list and I need to find the average score per student. For this I will need the total score in the column and the count.

I tried using PowerAutomate flow but I am not sure how I can filter via email as the email entry is a lookup column and I'm facing issues

Example

*Viva Feedback*

| Name | Confidence | Knowledge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abraham | 4 | 3 |
| David | 3 | 4 |
| Abraham | 2 | 4 |
| Abraham | 4 | 3 |
| Mary | 2 | 3 |
| David | 4 | 3 |
| Mary | 2 | 4 |

Expected Output in new list(we need dump in case disputes arise)

| Name | Confidence | Knowledge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abraham | 3.7 | 3.7 |
| David | 3.5 | 3 |
| Mary | 2 | 3.5 |

The output needs to be a new list as this will be used as Database for UI to pick from

Comment: Are you using Power Automate (MS Flows)? I think we can fulfil this requirements using Power Automate. Also, do you have a separate list containing all the students? Basically, looping through the student list and calculate average for each student and then store it into a separate list (summary)?

Comment: Hi Matiur,

Thanks for your reply.

I did try Power Automate to average the values exactly as you mentioned but hit a roadblock while trying to filter because the email is from a lookup column and I am not able to figure out how to filter

Comment: "Email": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "@@odata.type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "Id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "Value": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }

Comment: This is the JSON of the email object I am trying to reference
I'm very new to this, so apologies if this is a stupid question/

Comment: I can help on Power Automate (PA). Can you describe the steps in your PA? Is [Email] a 
lookup column in your [Viva Feedback] list? I need to construct the lists before I can provide the solution. So, the more info that you can provide the easier it will be for me. Of course, provide sample/dummy data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping on this. I'll try to explain. Here's how the lists are created

Central DB(Student Details)
|Name | Email | Avg of Skill 1 | Avg of Skill 2|......

Feedback(per avtivity) Eg - Viva
|Email<Lookup from Central DB>    | Confidence | Knowledge |

My flow is currently trying to filter the Viva table based on email and count the rows to calculate average per person. I'm having issues with filtering based on email. Is this because it is a lookup value?

Comment: So, [Email] in Student is a "Single Line of Text", and [Email] in Viva is a "LookUp" column right? You still should be able to filter it. I will give it a try later today and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps showing how to calculate average **Confidence** and **Knowledge** for each student by using Power Automate. For this sample, two lists being used: 1) *Student*, stores unique student information including Email, and 2) *Feedback*, stores students' feedback values against [Email], which is a lookup column referring to *Student* list.

**Sample values for SharePoint Lists**

[image]

[image]

**Screenshots with Details of Power Automate**
[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2 & 3

[image]

### Detail 4

[image]

**Expression 1**

```
div(variables('varConfidenceSum'), variables('varStudentFeedbackCount'))
```

### Final output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!! I am working on this now!! Appreciate the help